# Checking to see if a user has filled in a table in Matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matrix, uitableview

Can this `if (size(cost,1) == 2 && size(limit,1) == 2)` expression be used? Because I want to take the data from `cost` table and `limit` table. The `cost` table is 4 by 3 table and `limit` table is 4 by 2 table. So i want to take the data (which are input from user) from `limit` table. I have this code:

```
if P1 < limit(1,1)
    P1 = limit(1,1);
    lambdanew = P1*2*cost(1,3) + cost(1,2);
```

I can execute my program only if the user inserts the data into limit table but if the user did not insert the data, so it will be an error saying this:

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> fyp_editor>Mybutton_Callback at 100
        if P1 < limit(1,1)
```

So my question is how I can make `if` statement for the limit table if the user did not enter the data?

Is it `limit(0)`,  `limit = 0` or `limit == 0`??

Comment: Can you change the topic line of your question to a single-line summary that will help passers-by immediately determine if they can answer the question? _Sell_ us your question!!! Topics like "I have a question" and "help me" don't illuminate your subject matter.

Comment: @bob: thank you. i am new with this

Comment: Evidently. Bob meant change the title to summarize *what the question is*. The fact that you've posted a question here does an excellent job of implying that you have a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you initialize the limit table somehow so you know it exists but that the user didn't enter any information in it?  If limit table is 4 by 2, try `limit = zeros(4,2)`. Hope that helps.

Comment: is it exactly the same error?  if you index into limit(1,1) with limit being defined as zeros(4,2), it shouldn't be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that `limit` is an array of size (4,2), you can do the following

```
if ~all(size(limit)==[4 2]))
    h = errordlg('please fill in all values for "limit"');
    uiwait(h)
    return
end
```

Thus, the user gets an error message popping up, after which the callback stops executing.